# Classification of biclosed monoidal structures on the $2$-category of $2$-categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, 2-categories

[This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82322397.pdf) proves that the category of small categories and functors between them admits exactly two monoidal biclosed categories: the cartesian tensor product and the funny tensor product.

Is there a similar classification for monoidal biclosed $2$-category structures on the $2$-category of $2$-categories, $2$-functors, and $2$-transformations? In particular, are the Cartesian, funny, and Gray tensor products the unique such monoidal structures?

Comment: Crossposted: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402258/classification-of-biclosed-monoidal-structures-on-the-2-category-of-2-catego)